# What is the syntax for setting the value of FormArray using FormBuilder

Tags: angular

I cannot figure out how to patch values on an Angular form built with `FormBuilder`. It seems like it should be fairly obvious, but I just can't seem to get it to work. I am building a form with:

```
buildForm() {
const controlArray = this.redirectPortsForm.get('redirectPortsArray') as FormArray;

Object.keys(this.ports).forEach((i) => {
  controlArray.push(
    this.formBuilder.group({
      //port_entry: new FormControl({ value: this.ports[i].redirect_text, disabled: false })
      port_entry: new FormControl({ value: "", disabled: false })
    })
  )
})

console.log(controlArray.controls)
}
```

I've commented out a line for testing by intentionally setting it to nothing so it will be obvious when I successfully set it. I have a loop where I would like to set the value. Here is a simplified version:

```
const controlArray = this.redirectPortsForm.get('redirectPortsArray') as FormArray;
for (const [i, port] of ports.entries()) {
  controlArray.controls[i].patchValue({value: i.toString()});
}
```

I have tried many variations of this, but this is the latest. Is there something more to it? Am I missing something obvious? That code throws no errors, but also doesn't patch the values.

Comment: Shouldn't there be `{ port_entry: i.toString() }`?

Comment: @RachidO I'd say `FormArray` can contain `AbstractControl` instances: `FormControl`, `FormGroup`, `FormArray`. So, you're not limited to `FormControl`s.

Comment: My understanding was the same as @AndreiGătej's - FormArray contains AbstractControl which includes FormGroup. Now, I'm pretty new so I'm still wrapping my head around all this and FormGroup may not be necessary, but the docs seemed to indicate FormGroup was fair game. AndreiGătej, to answer your question, probably? What would the syntax be though? That's the part that's getting me.

Comment: Try to replace the ‘patchValue’s argument with what I suggested 3 comments above. Also, I’d recommend checking out [this article](https://indepth.dev/a-thorough-exploration-of-angular-forms/) on forms.

Comment: @AndreiGătej ohhhhhhh that's obvious now. I had spent so much time looking at this code set I forgot I had changed it to that for StackOverflow. That was it. bahahaha well, before looking at the problem again I spent a bunch of time reading about forms again so I guess I learned something . Thanks! Do you want to submit that as an answer and I'll mark it as correct?

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful! Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `FormGroup` has this structure `{ port_entry: new FormControl(...) }`, the `patchValue`'s argument should be `{ port_entry: i.toString() }`.